# Network No Internet

Tags: windows-7, network-adapter

I have a user experiencing network connectivity but no internet. Using a windows 7 dell desktop and LAN connection.

I have tried ipconfig /release dnsflush /renew

Uninstalled and reinstalled the network adapter and it comes back for 15minutes and then stops working.

Even tried assigning a static ip to the workstation.

Thoughts?

Cheers J

Answer (score 0):

#### I have a user experiencing network connectivity but no internet.

Try completely reinitialising all network states.

Run the following commands in an elevated `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults (reboot required):

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I came in monday to finder the lease on the internal IP had renewed and it had fixed itself.