# Multiple websites timing out only on my device and not others, can only be connected to via VPN

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns

This happened all of a sudden. I first noticed when packages wouldn't load in Visual Studio's NuGet Package Manager.

Upon further investigation (and, ironically, due to it) I've noticed a lot of sites are refusing to connect. Examples being:

- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/
- https://nuget.org/
- https://www.windowscentral.com/

Doing an `nslookup` I get this result:

```
nslookup developercommunity.visualstudio.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.42.129

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    vsf-prod.westus.cloudapp.azure.com
Address:  138.91.249.18
Aliases:  developercommunity.visualstudio.com
```

**Ping:**

```
ping https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/
Ping request could not find host https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/. Please check the name and try again.
```

**Pathping:**

```
pathping developercommunity.visualstudio.com

Tracing route to vsf-prod.westus.cloudapp.azure.com [138.91.249.18]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
  0  DESKTOP-MDKBS3O [192.168.42.182]
  1  192.168.42.129
  2  Linksys05191 [10.40.161.215]
  3  192.168.1.1
  4  172.30.96.51
  5  172.30.96.1
  6     *        *        *
Computing statistics for 125 seconds...
            Source to Here   This Node/Link
Hop  RTT    Lost/Sent = Pct  Lost/Sent = Pct  Address
  0                                           DESKTOP-MDKBS3O [192.168.42.182]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  1    0ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  192.168.42.129
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  2   11ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  Linksys05191 [10.40.161.215]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  3   11ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  192.168.1.1
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  4   20ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  172.30.96.51
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  5   23ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  172.30.96.1

Trace complete.
```

Disabling anti-virus and firewall doesn't help.

After doing an in-place Windows 10 install, the issue was fixed for 5 days. The sites stopped working again today, and upon trying the in-place install again, nothing happened. Only difference was that last time the install caused an update as I was on 1903.

**Using a VPN fixes the problem. However, it is not my ISP  blocking the sites as they work fine on other devices even without a VPN.**

Comment: Have you checked if your hosts file has been modified

Comment: `https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/` is not a domain. `developercommunity.visualstudio.com` is a domain. Please re-test.

Comment: @Ramhound The hosts file was empty, but even upon following [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/972034/how-to-reset-the-hosts-file-back-to-the-default] to reset it, the same issue remains

Comment: @user1686 updated question

Comment: What does `ping developercommunity.visualstudio.com` return?

Comment: @DavidPostill `Request timed out`

Comment: To be more specific, `Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),`

Comment: What does `pathping developercommunity.visualstudio.com` return?

Comment: Try restarting your router, then [a complete network reset](https://superuser.com/a/1412710/337631)

Comment: @DavidPostill Already did those two. Pathping is in updated answer

Comment: `172.30.96.1` is a private IP address so it's still inside your ISPs network. Call your ISP.

Comment: @DavidPostill It works fine on all devices except this specific windows device. Now that I remember, this all started happening after I installed NetLimiter. Uninstalling didn't help

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: The simplest method is to perform an in-place upgrade to the same version you are already running.  All you do is download the appropriate ISO for the version and edition you are currently running, mount the ISO, and launch setup.exe from within Windows

Comment: @Ramhound that seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it fixed it but now it's back to where it was after a couple of days.

Comment: Try to test while booting in [Safe Mode with Networking](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode). Not all commands will work in this mode, so do multiple tests.

Comment: The test results you posted are all to be expected.  Ping (and PathPing) aren't really the proper test for this.  Instead, try telneting into the web server with `telnet developercommunity.visualstudio.com 80` and see if it connects (either you get an error [bad], or you get a blank prompt [good]).  If connected (blank screen) then try sending `HEAD /` and see if there is a response.  That's a better test of an HTTP server connection.

Comment: Do try my above comment for booting in Safe Mode with Networking.

Answer (score 0):

First, the MS does site not respond to ping. Period. It's an HTTTP/HTTPS site, and they restrict response.

Second, check DNS name resolution. Your DNS server may be having issues.

- [Flush the DNS cache](https://www.technipages.com/flush-and-reset-the-dns-resolver-cache-using-ipconfig).

  - Open CMD prompt as Administrator.
  - Enter `ipconfig /flushdns`.
- If you have manually [selected a DNS server, either go to automatic DNS resolution](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-pcs-dns-settings-windows-10), or
- Try [Closudflare DNS resolution](https://www.cloudflare.com/dns/), or
- Try [Google DNS resolution](https://www.howtogeek.com/164981/how-to-switch-to-opendns-or-google-dns-to-speed-up-web-browsing/).

Comment: I've tried all of these and unfortunately, none have worked

Comment: DNS is clearly working, but pathping stops at `172.30.96.1`, a private IP address so still inside either his or the ISP's network.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it like a firewall is stopping packets at `172.30.96.1`. If you are connected to internet using your ISP, then ask their helpdesk to stop firewall there. If it is in LAN, then ask the computer's owner to create firewall exception. There is no problem with tour DNS resolution.

Comment: I doubt this is the case, as the problem only occurs on a single device and not others.